# User Provisioning and Deprovisioning with BaseCamp API

Tags: api, basecamp

I'm trying to figure out with API I can use to create and delete users inside Basecamp.

I'm looking to both Basecamp v1, v2 and v3.

The only method I find is:

```
 POST /projects/1/accesses.json
```

https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/accesses.md

That appears to be on PROJECTS, so with a specific "scope".

How can I create and delete users via API?

Is there something SCIM-Like for provisioning?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (only looked at Basecamp 3), there is absolutely no mechanism for this that's published. I want this feature too!